# Running plugins without opening Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Using Eclipse IDE we have created plugin which is used to open the Directory Dialog on selection of the option openDialog in menu bar which performs the operation of reading the file names inside the directory and then creates a new file and pops up the Save Dialog in which we can specify the desired location to save the created file. So to run this plugin we need Eclipse IDE to be opened.

Question 1: Can we run that plugin without opening the Eclipse IDE.

Question 2: I want to export this plugin in the form of .exe or jar such that when I run that .exe in the windows we want to start executing that plugin.

Finally we want to run the plugins as Standalone application without opening the eclipse IDE

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't run a plug-in on its own, it will depend on many other plug-ins and the Eclipse/OSGi framework.

You may be able to write an Eclipse Rich Client Program (RCP) standalone application containing the plug-in and the other required plug-ins.